# Ajax and php Response doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I really like the help here and normally i figured out any Problem so far just by reading the existing Posts. However this time i can't quiet figure out whats wrong in my code.

I want to write dataildata values of a specific Tablerow in a form. The Data is stored in an mysql database and I access it with php.

The Probleme is that it seems that the Ajax request isn't working. neighter the success nor the error Event get triggered. Although the alter(id) works just fine.

Here is the Ajax call of the function:

```
$( "#table1 tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert( id );
   $.ajax({
    type:       'POST',
    url:        'getDetailData.php',
    dataType:   'json',
    data:       {id : id },
    success:    function(data){
        $("#inputWstId").val(data.WST-ID);
        $("#inputSerialNumber").val(data.SERNO);    
        $("#inputName").val(data.NAME);
        alert(data.NAME);
        alert ("Test");
    },
    error:      function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
});
```

and here is the .php File:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   $connect = include 'connect.php'; 
   if (isset ($_POST['id'])){
       $id= $_POST['id']; 
   }
   $query = "  select * FROM pci WHERE id= ". $id ;
   $result = mysql_query($query);       
   $ligne  = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $data = array(
      "WST-ID"    => $ligne["WST_ID"],
      "SERNO"     => $ligne["SERNO"],
      "NAME"    => $ligne["NAME"]
   );
  mysql_close($connect);
  echo (json_encode($data));
?>
```

If you Need more sourcecode or anything else just let me know- Thank you so much for your help!!

WST_ID instead of WST-ID really worked - thank you so much !! 
Why is it, that I can't use a "-" in my values ... guess there is a lot more to learn ;)

Comment: What does it show in browser console?.. You can check the network tab to actually see the request being thrown..

Comment: Some time POST does not work properly with Ajax try to use $_REQUEST instead and add an exit after  echo (json_encode($data)); line and you dont need header('Content-Type: application/json'); line as well.Tehn use console.log(data) to check if you are getting json response

Comment: comment code in .php file and print some text to see if there is no issue with php code. Also check consol and net tab in firebug

Comment: The first post (which is somehow already deletet already was the right one. I had to Change WST-ID to WST_ID and now it works just fine. - thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 In the PHP part you need add two more headers :

     header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
     header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'); 

 Add the two line of coding with the:

       header('Content-Type: application/json');

 change the: 

       echo (json_encode($data));

 to:

       print $my_json = json_encode($data);

 or:

       print_r ($my_json);



 Hope it will work.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to give absolute url. Only `getDetailData.php` will not work. Try `http://xyzabc.com/getDetailData.php`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This is example link and not the actual link. The answer is provided and not the link